# Fail to load json & i18n directories from visual studio 2013 SAPUI5

Tags: json, sapui5, sap-fiori

i have problem in loading json or i18n file in visual studio 2013. Noted, it has no problem in sap hana studio environment.

Below is my code:

```
<script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"sap.ui.demo.myFiori": "./"}'>
</script>

var oView = sap.ui.view({
        id : "app",
        viewName : "sap.ui.demo.myFiori.view.App",
        type : "JS",
        viewData : { component : this }
});

var i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
        bundleUrl : "i18n/messageBundle.properties"
});
oView.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");

var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/mock.json");
```

oView.setModel(oModel);

Below is my visual studio 2013 directories:

- UI5Application3

-i18n

```
-i18n.properties

-messageBundle.properties
```

-model

```
-mock.json
```

Please help me. All your suggestion is highly appreciated

Comment: Please help me, Anyone who has the experience in developing sapui5, openui5, sap fiori in visual studio 2013 environment will greatly help.

Comment: Did you have a look at the new tutorial section in the Developer guide for UI5 - https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/df86bfbeab0645e5b764ffa488ed57dc.html